# Count Two Tables on shared date in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two separate customer tables A and B. I am trying to count the customers created in A and B in the same query by date. I can get the right data with Union All but not properly grouped.

I want the data like so:

```
date,count A created, count B created
4/15/2015,1,5
```

Instead of:

```
date, count
4/15/2015, 1
4/15/2015, 5
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: hi winged panther, will try it out! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a cte, just have to be carefull if you dont have date in every day. In that case you would need a date table to get 0 when no sales.

Also try not use reserved words like `date` as fieldnames

```
with countA as (
     SELECT date, count(*) as CountA
     from tableA
     group by date
),
countB as (
     SELECT date, count(*) as CountB
     from tableB
     group by date
)
SELECT A.date, A.CountA, B.CountB
FROM CountA  A
INNER JOIN  CountB B
   ON A.date = B.date
```

With a table `AllDates` to solve day without sales

```
SELECT T.date, 
       CASE 
          WHEN A.CountA IS NULL THEN 0
          ELSE A.CountA
       END as CountA,
       CASE 
          WHEN B.CountB IS NULL THEN 0
          ELSE B.CountB
       END as CountB

FROM AllDates T 
LEFT JOIN CountA  A
       ON T.date = A.date
LEFT JOIN CountB B
       ON T.date = B.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.dte
      ,a.count a_created
      ,b.count b_created 
from
 (select dte,count(*)from table_a group by dte) a
,(select dte,count(*)from table_b group by dte) b
where b.dte=a.dte
```

[***SQLFIDDLE DEMO***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af422/1)

***OR***

You can use achieve this by using PostgreSQL's [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html)

start bty creating `CREATE EXTENSION if not exists tablefunc;`

and following as an example

```
create table table_a (dte date,is_created int);
create table table_b (dte date,is_created int);

insert into table_a values('2015-10-07',1);
insert into table_a values('2015-10-07',1);
insert into table_a values('2015-10-07',1);
insert into table_a values('2015-10-07',1);
insert into table_a values('2015-10-07',1);

insert into table_b values('2015-10-07',2);
```

by using `crosstab()` the select should be

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'select dte,''a_created'' col,count(*) created from table_a group by dte
    union all
    select dte, ''b_created'' col,count(*) created from table_b group by dte') 
AS ct("date" DATE, "a_created" BIGINT, "b_created" BIGINT);
```